# emacs auto-complete behavior with underscores in python mode

Tags: emacs, python, autocomplete, syntax

In my `.emacs` I have the following line of code:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "." python-mode-syntax-table)
```

This is so that commands like `forward-word` and `backward-kill-word` stop at any underscores that are in a word.  This is different behavior than the default, and it is the behavior I want.  The problem is that then `auto-complete-mode` also respects underscores as word boundaries in an undesirable way.  For example, if I have a variable called `foo_var`, and I type `fo` and then try to complete, it will only complete to `foo` not `foo_var`.

In `text-mode` and `c-mode` the behavior is exactly what I want i.e. motion obeys underscores, but `auto-complete-mode` will complete across them.  What do I need to change in my `auto-complete-mode` configuration to fix this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get my problem solved.  I did a diff on the syntax tables loaded for both `python-mode` and `c-mode` (using `C-h s`).  I noticed that in `c-mode`, the underscore was a symbol character ("_") and in `python-mode` the underscore was a punctuation character (".").  So, I simply changed the aforementioned line of code to

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "_" python-mode-syntax-table)
```